# Tire (elasticsearch) is not updating when I do a update_all()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I am using Tire in ruby on rails to connect with ElastiSearch.

When I modify an element's parameters with `update_attributes`, Tire automatically updates the index to reflect this change.

However, when I modify many elements simultaneously by doing `update_all`, Tire does not update the index, and it becomes out of sync with my database.

Is this a bug in Tire? Is there a workaround?

Comment: have you submitted an issue on github for Tire? Karmi is pretty good about responding it issues and brainstorming about possible solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [ActiveRecord#update_all documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class):

> Updates all records with details given if they match a set of conditions supplied, limits and order can also be supplied. This method constructs a single SQL UPDATE statement and sends it straight to the database. It does not instantiate the involved models and it does not trigger Active Record callbacks.

So *Tire* does not update anything, because the callbacks are not called...

You have to either:

a) use `find_each` and call the `save` method

b) use `update_all`, but then do a full re-index.

Comment: I like (a) since it looks like the functionality you want involves updating the Rails object, NOT a straight SQL UPDATE call.  There might be other thing you want to be happen on the object besides re-indexing.